# How to use "Read More" button in laravel with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello everyone How to use Read More button With laravel and Javascript.

Laravel Code:

```
 <p>
            {!! str_limit(($activity->subject->discussion), 300, '') !!}
            @if (strlen($activity->subject->discussion) > 300)
                <span id="dots">...</span>
                <span id="more" style="display:  none;">{{ substr($activity->subject->discussion, 300) }}</span>
                
            @endif

            
            
            </p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-small" onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
```

Here  i think if condition also count the html tags

Javascript Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
    var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
        moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
</script>
```

using these read more button is work But when we click on any read more button every time open the first paragraph
and also in if condition  display "read more" button which data length is less than 300.

Comment: "_every time open the first paragraph_" That is most likely because you then have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute ("dots", "more") - which is invalid anyway, `id` attributes _must_ be unique in a document.

Comment: @brombeer So what i can do for these problem?

Comment: Use classes any maybe `closest()` to find the related "more" and "dots" (Or maybe make this a reusable Vue component)